# why does shuffle function not working in php8?

Tags: php

I am stuck, how do I fix this code. I am using php8. in php7 this code is working, maybe anyone can help me? can explain what happened?

```
<?php

$arr = explode(" ","a7a062cd9dfted04e 6dc4ft7bcefg2934fb");

print_r (shuffle($arr));

?>
```

results

1

I am trying to print the explode array value and the values are there

```
<?php

$arr = explode(" ","a7a062cd9dfted04e 6dc4ft7bcefg2934fb");

foreach ($arr as $s) {

print_r($s);
print_r("\n");

?>
```

so thanks for your help

Comment: Added code tags to make your code readable. Please [see the manual for shuffle()](https://www.php.net/shuffle), `shuffle(array &$array): true`. Return value is always `true` (or `1` when output as a string). You want to do the `shuffle()` without using its return value, since it _works by reference_ on your target array.

Comment: In other news, your code will output `1` in any version of PHP, even [4.3.0 - see demo](https://3v4l.org/mRBUb#v4.3.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = explode(" ","a7a062cd9dfted04e 6dc4ft7bcefg2934fb");
shuffle($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

shuffle function always return true, you are printing shuffle returns not the actual array, use provide code to print the result of shuffle.
see https://www.php.net/shuffle